# how to create transparent label in toolbox in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a  `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip` which contains a `Label`.

The `ToolStrip` has a special fancy background. But the label is just gray.
[image: Toolbar]

It's not possible to use transparency because the parent of `ToolStrip` is a form. Also it's not possible to change the parent, because the collection of Controls in `ToolStrip` is read only.

Is it possible to create a `Label` that is transparent and which has a `ToolStrip` parent?

Comment: In Winforms/WebForms/WPF/Silverlight/... ?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip

Comment: *System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip* An overzealous editor removed it from the original post.. (Now added back for clarity).

Answer (score 1):

If you just delete the assigned background color of the `ToolStripLabel` then it ought to inherit the background of its parent `ToolStrip`.  I use a custom `ToolStripRenderer` to draw a customized background for tool strips, and my labels do not need any special handling in order to inherit the parent's background.  Just make sure you aren't trying to assign a background color.

Comment: It's System.Windows.Forms.Label, I can't do what you mentioned

Comment: RogerN said that, theres a `toolstriplabel` that you could add to `ToolStrip`. try explore http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you're using a ToolStrip?  Items managed by a ToolStrip must be derived from ToolStripItem.  Also, the screenshot you added does not look like a ToolStrip.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a shot.

Set the backcolor of the label to Color.Transparent. 
Then you have to add the label directly to the control collection of the control of which you want the label to appear transparent on top of.